# Proof of Van Aubel's theorem using Complex Numbers

Tags: calculus, geometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

on each edge of a quadrilateral ABCD you build a square such that the points H, G, F, E are the centers of these squares (the intersection of the diagonals).

I need to use complex numbers to prove that FH and EG are equal and ortogonal to eachother.

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: It is Van Aubel's theorem ; I have taken the liberty to modify your title accordingly.  See [there](https://www.i-repository.net/il/user_contents/02/G0000031Repository/repository/keidaironshu_063_006_131-138.pdf) for a proof involving complex numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1^{\rm st}$ hint:

Given two different complex numbers $a$ and $b$ the number $i(b-a)$ considered as a vector is $\vec{ab}$ rotated $90^\circ$ counterclockwise; in particular, it has the same length.

$2^{\rm nd}$ hint:

Assume that the quadrilateral  is convex and that its vertices $A, B, C, D$ are arranged counterclockwise. Let $a, b, c, d$ be the complex coordinates of the four vertices. Then the other two vertices of the square over the side $AB$ have complex coordinates $a-i(b-a)$ and $b-i(b-a)$.

Comment: I don't know how to use your hint :(